# Is one big for loop faster than than two small ones?

Tags: java

In the code, I have made two for loops:

```
for(int y = 0;i < HEIGHT; y++){
for(int y = 0;i < WIDTH; y++){
//lots of switch cases
}
}
```

and I wonder, is it faster to use one for loop like this? :

```
for(int i = 0;i < HEIGHT*WIDTH; i++){
//lots of switch cases
}
```

Comment: No way to say without knowing what's inside those `case`s.

Comment: You won't be able to measure the difference unless the HEIGHT and WIDTH are really huge and the amount of work done in the switch is really small.   Otherwise the time spent "executing the loop statement" is an insignificant fraction.  You should write code that is logically clear UNTIL you have actual measurements that support doing otherwise.

Comment: And of course, your two-loops version won't work. You mixed up x, y, and i.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual newbie misconception: java performance doesn't come out of "clever java **source** code".

The key part is: the optimisations that the just-in-time compiler does at runtime. And that starts with: the JIT deciding whether code is invoked often enough to be *worth* optimizing.

Thus, the real answer to (most) java performance questions is:

- write simple code that is correct and *readable*
- as that enables the JIT to optimize things when necessary AND
- it also enables you to improve your code later on, in case you really wrote code that is for this or that reason leading to performance issues

(and that 3rd point, you figure that because your users/tests unveil "bad performance", and then you did a lot of measuring to identify the true root cause of that problem)

Thus, as said: focus on writing *correct* code that is easy to read and understand, and do **not** worry about performance until much later.

Answer (score 1):

No.

As mentioned, you should determine your end condition before you use in it a loop, meaning that you should have

```
int total = height*width;
for( int i=0; i < total; ++i ) {
    // ...
}
```

so that total isn't constantly computed during the loop. That said, everyone does it and I would expect the compiler to optimize your version into this version anyway.

The real issue, as I see it, is that in the loop you may have to reverse the computation from the `total`, meaning that you might have to have

```
int total = height*width;
for( int i=0; i < total; ++i ) {
    int x = total / width;
    int y = total % height;
    call(x,y);
}
```

This would be slower than

```
for( int i=0; i < width; ++i ) {
    for( int j=0; i < height; ++i ) {
        call(i,j);
    }
}
```

which should be faster. This does not take into consideration "branching operations" in CPU's.  See [Branchless Programming: Why "If" is Sloowww... and what we can do about it!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bVJ-mWWL7cE).

EDIT: And yes, the most salient comment in this thread is that you should worry about readability much more performance.